# Limit at 0 involving e, sine and cosine.

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm a newbie, please pardon my ignorance. I've been trying to solve this limit, to no avail.

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{-x} + \sin x - \cos x}{x} = 0$$

I figured I'd break the fraction into 3 parts, one for each term of the numerator: I know that $\frac {sin x}{x} = 1$. But then, Wolfram Alpha says, a two-sided limit for the other two members doesn't exist. Which means I'd end up with anything, after summing the terms, but 0.

It should be mentioned we've skipped some theory in the book, which may be necessary to solve this limit.

Does someone know how to solve it?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I'm sorry, I made a typo… it's _minus_ cos x.

Comment: Write $e^{-x} - \cos x = (e^{-x}-1) + (1-\cos x)$.

Comment: Indiidual limits don't exist. Only $e^{-x}-\cos x$ together go to $0$, so you can't treat them seperately.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see what you did there. Brilliant! Thank you. :D

Comment: Alternatively note that this limit is the definition of the derivaitve of $x\mapsto e^{-x}+\sin(x)-\cos(x)$ at $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With l'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-e^{-x}+\cos x+\sin x}1=0$$

Comment: Could you please show me how to use this rule? (Which we haven't studied yet, pardon my ignorance…) -- Even if it's showing intermediate steps, or a generic explanation of what the rule does.

Comment: You can learn it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: @ajotaxe I should differentiate the numerator and denominator, and proceed as normal? I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Thanks to Daniel Fischer and Orion.

$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-x} + \sin x - \cos x}{x}$$

I opportunely add, and then subtract one to the numerator. With this, one can cancel $e$ and $\cos$.

$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-x} - 1 + \sin x + 1 - \cos x}{x} =$$

$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{(e^{0} - 1) + \sin x + (1 - \cos 0)}{x}$$

$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{0 + \sin x + 0}{x}$$

$$ = 1$$

Comment: You cannot replace $e^{-x}-1$ and $1-\cos x$ with $0$. (If you could, then you could replace $\sin x$ with $0$ as well. I'm sure you can see the problem with that.) You need to separate the limit into three parts: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-x}-1}{x} + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} + \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x}$$ Each is a "$0/0$" form that needs to be handled individually.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you can expand these functions using Taylor expansion at x = 0. 
It'll get help you to get rid of the problematic terms 1 and x, the higher order terms won't matter.
$$e^{-x} = 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!}+...
\\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+...
\\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+...
\\e^{-x}+sin(x)-cos(x) = 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!}+... + x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+...-1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^4}{4!}+...=2*(\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+...)
$$